# favor composition over inheritance: practical problems

Tags: c#, inheritance, composition

In a C# application, I've got a behaviour that I would like to be available in different classes that not necessarily share the same ancestor. What better opportunity to 'favour composition over inheritance?"

In this case not only composition is a better way, but can also be the only way.
Unfortunately, the code is the following. I left only the relevant part, obviously it would make little sense to delegate only this, but this is the problematic part.

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

   }
```

Turns out that since PropertyChanged is an event, it can only be raised inside the declaring class.

I evaluated all the proposed alternatives to this, found in this S&O question:
[Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378339/raise-an-event-of-a-class-from-a-different-class-in-c-sharp)
and all of them seems a bit of a hack. That is, events are not meant to be delegated. Fundamentally, I would like that someone proof me to be wrong on this point.

Unfortunately this seems to be another case of the pattern: you use inheritance? no no no, there is a better approach. And when you try to implement it you suddenly bump into problems that require various levels of hacking the language or bringing complexity of the solution to an whole other level.

At the end of the day inheritance or composition is not a marriage, so I don't want to stay with either of them for life; I considered myself to be married with the non-duplication, or DRY principle. So I wanted to find a good way of not repeating the code. Here I simply cannot find a reasonably-simple solution and hope that someone else that has already bumped into this problem proposed some perhaps 'third way' solution.

Comment: fody propertychanged

Comment: INPC has been major PITA since it was created. There are multiple ways people tried to simplify it or code-gen it or whatever. [Quick research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inotifypropertychanged) should show you all the available options.

Comment: Really. I would close this as duplicate, if we could mark [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist) as duplicates.

Comment: Insisting on composition over inheritance (and absolute DRY) is just more dogma for no good reason.  Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: Robert, it seems like there is no one here. Inheritance brings duplication, composition is not supported (in a reasonably easy way) by the language.

Comment: Composition is supported perfectly fine in C#, just not in this specific context.  Blame the design of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, not the language.

Comment: FWIW, I just use [`Fody.PropertyChanged`](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) on all my classes that require an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.  Problem solved, no inheritance required.

Comment: interesting, i always thought that inheritance is a language thing while composition is just a design that leverages interfaces and properties. What is this 'explicit' support of inheritance that we can find in c#? You mean the explicit implemetation of interfaces?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Inheritance has been fully supported in C# since version 1.

Comment: inheritance? I was talking about composition not inheritance :-(

Comment: Your last comment asked: "What is this 'explicit' support of inheritance that we can find in c#?"

Comment: sorry wrong word. It was 'composition'

Comment: Have a look at Fody.PropertyChanged.

Answer (score 4):

There are certain things that do require inheritance.  In absence of other language features, this example would be one of them.  Note that the phrase is to ***favor*** composition over inheritance.  That does not mean throw out inheritance where it is warranted.

However, C# specifically does provide a nice out here.  That's the use of [Extension Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).  Since `INotifyPropertyChanged` declares the event and the identifies the behavioral pattern, you can implement the specific feature you are talking about using this feature:

```
public static class FrameworkExtensions
{
    public static void NotifyPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged model,
            [CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        model.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(model, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

The important thing to make it a reality is that the user needs to import the namespace this is declared in.  If there are other framework classes that are commonly used in code, that is probably done for you.

Comment: This does require C# 6.0.

Comment: It still does not compile. `error CS4022: The CallerMemberNameAttribute may only be applied to parameters with default values`. Fix that and you get `error CS0079: The event 'INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=` and `error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'e' of 'PropertyChangedEventHandler.Invoke(object, PropertyChangedEventArgs)'`

Comment: Doesn't work with either .NET 4.6 and .NET 4.7. Same error  "The event 'INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged'  can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=..."

Comment: @SeanReid, Sorry about that.  I have addressed the default value problem and the missing parameter problem.  Theoretically the code should compile.

Comment: I am not on one of my machines that has Visual Studio installed at the moment.

Comment: @helb, C# 6 was released five years ago. If someone is still using an even older version of the compiler, then needing to use inheritance for this task is the least of their problems.

Comment: This does not compile